# Canon MP280 scanner not recognised in 12.04 after updates

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon, scanner

I have had my Canon MP280 scanner working but since various updates it is no longer recognised despite following all the "answers" on this site and others. It does not work at all with simple scan, scangearmp or gimp. Nothing recognises it. 
The printer part still works.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, in the terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

you should get a prompt to install new packages, install them. Report back.

It would be helpful if you provided us with a list of specific things you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time.I have tried to follow these instructions before, but it seems to hit an error. Here is the terminal output:

Comment: W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E585066A30C18A2B

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/stable/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: The above did not seem to work but Ijust noticed that the update manager had some scan updates. After installing them the scanner can be found and workd again with scangear!

Comment: open synaptic package manager. Go to Settings > Repositories. open the Other software tab and remove the ppa you added through the command line. Otherwise it will keep messing with your updates. Glad it's working. Whenever you run into an issue, always run an update first.